# What were Ajax's mutations?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the *Deadpool* movie I recall Ajax saying that when underwent the forced mutation process he gained super reflexes and then he severed all his nerve endings (or something like that) so he does not feel pain or "anything". Where did his seemingly above normal strength come from?

Also, Ajax is stabbed many times in critical areas (shoulder near heart, and inner thigh). I can understand how he is able remove the Deadpool's sword without pain as per the above, but what prevented him from bleeding out?

Overall question, **what is the full extent of Ajax's mutations?**

If the comics have an answer that the movie ignores, the comics are acceptable.

Comment: It's not fully discussed in the film.  It is in the comics. Would that be OK?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Comics would be fine. I will update the Q too.

Comment: http://marvel.com/universe/Ajax_(Francis)

Comment: Super strength seems to come free with almost any physical mutation

Comment: _Please_ call him _Francis_

Comment: Arguably, if you can't feel pain then the normal feedback mechanisms that prevent you from lifting too much wouldn't work either.  Vamping on Dresden a bit here, but it's a thought.  I'm also not pulling from Deadpool canon, so no answer.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb for the Weapon-X program, in canon, was using Wolverine's DNA to augment soldiers. It became the alternative to the other Super Soldier Serum program.

In the movie he - Ajax - refers to his serum as Adrenaline-X. He claims the serum kicks in when the body hits it's stress threshold. Much like Angel (Dust) with her Super Strength that doesn't explain how she is Super Tough and handling punching and being punched by Colossus, like Deadpool can't - and he can regenerate.

So my answer would have to be the Weapon-X serum gives enhanced toughness but only Deadpool got the half-Wolvie degree, and in the movie they explain that's his specific power. Though I was looking around about the reference in Wolverine Origins where Wade has Super Reflexes as he is. In the comics he has The Punisher level combat skills, so that makes sense to me.